# Why is Hindi Text not appearing correctly in safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, safari

I am trying to display hindi text. But its not loading correctly.
I tried to simply paste the text in a new file and it is working, what might be the case that in this case it is not working?
The hindi script is the second span with class word w2.

```js
"use strict";

let words = document.querySelectorAll(".word");
words.forEach((word) => {
  let letters = word.textContent.split("");
  word.textContent = "";
  letters.forEach((letter) => {
    let span = document.createElement("span")
    span.textContent = letter;
    span.className = "letter";
    word.append(span);
  });
});

let currentWordIndex = 0;
let maxWordIndex = words.length - 1;
words[currentWordIndex].style.opacity = "1";

let rotateText = () => {
  let currentWord = words[currentWordIndex];
  let nextWord =
    currentWordIndex === maxWordIndex ? words[0] : words[currentWordIndex + 1];
  //rotate out letters of current word
  Array.from(currentWord.children).forEach((letter, i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      letter.className = "letter out";
    }, i * 80)
  });

  //reveal and rotate in letters of next word
  nextWord.style.opacity = "1";
  Array.from(nextWord.children).forEach((letter, i) => {
    letter.className = "letter behind";
    setTimeout(() => {
      letter.className = "letter in";
    }, 340 + i * 80)
  });
  currentWordIndex =
    currentWordIndex === maxWordIndex ? 0 : currentWordIndex + 1;
};

rotateText();
setInterval(rotateText, 4000);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #222;
}

.rotating-text {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateX(-80px);
}

.rotating-text p {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.rotating-text p .word {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
}

.rotating-text p .word .letter {
  transform-origin: center center 25px;
}

.rotating-text p .word .letter.out {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.7, 0.2);
}

.rotating-text p .word .letter.in {
  transition: 0.8s ease;
}

.rotating-text p .word .letter.behind {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.w-1 {
  color: #e74c3c;
}

.w-2 {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.w-3 {
  color: #3498db;
}

.w-4 {
  color: #28cc71;
}

.w-5 {
  color: #f1c40f;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotating-text">
  <p>Hello! My Name is </p>
  <p>
    <span class="word w-1">Abhay_Chandra</span>
    <span class="word w-2">अभय चंद्रा </span>
    <span class="word w-3">アバイ・チャンドラ</span>
    <span class="word w-4">Абхай Чандра</span>
    <span class="word w-5">아바이 찬드라</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVBmc.png)

but when i normally type the hindi script , like in a p tag, it is appearing correctly.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do a grapheme split to split these characters correctly and to avoid breaking apart the important code points that form the "characters". Using `.split("")` splits on the code units of your string, which is too granular and ends up splitting code units apart from each other that you need to keep together. Doing a graphene split in JavaScript hasn't always been easy, however, somewhat recently a new API called `Intl.Segmenter` has made it easier to do this, but do be aware of the [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter/Segmenter#browser_compatibility):

```js
const graphemeSplit = (str, locale) => {
  const segmenter = new Intl.Segmenter(locale, {granularity: 'grapheme'});
  const segitr = segmenter.segment(str);
  return Array.from(segitr, ({segment}) => segment);
}
```

```js
"use strict";

const graphemeSplit = (str, locale) => {
  const segmenter = new Intl.Segmenter(locale, {granularity: 'grapheme'});
  const segitr = segmenter.segment(str);
  return Array.from(segitr, ({segment}) => segment);
}

let words = document.querySelectorAll(".word");
words.forEach((word) => {
  const locale = word.dataset.locale;
  let letters = graphemeSplit(word.textContent, locale);
  word.textContent = "";
  letters.forEach((letter) => {
    let span = document.createElement("span")
    span.textContent = letter;
    span.className = "letter";
    word.append(span);
  });
});

let currentWordIndex = 0;
let maxWordIndex = words.length - 1;
words[currentWordIndex].style.opacity = "1";

let rotateText = () => {
  let currentWord = words[currentWordIndex];
  let nextWord =
    currentWordIndex === maxWordIndex ? words[0] : words[currentWordIndex + 1];
  //rotate out letters of current word
  Array.from(currentWord.children).forEach((letter, i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      letter.className = "letter out";
    }, i * 80)
  });

  //reveal and rotate in letters of next word
  nextWord.style.opacity = "1";
  Array.from(nextWord.children).forEach((letter, i) => {
    letter.className = "letter behind";
    setTimeout(() => {
      letter.className = "letter in";
    }, 340 + i * 80)
  });
  currentWordIndex =
    currentWordIndex === maxWordIndex ? 0 : currentWordIndex + 1;
};

rotateText();
setInterval(rotateText, 4000);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #222;
}

.rotating-text {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateX(-80px);
}

.rotating-text p {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.rotating-text p .word {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
}

.rotating-text p .word .letter {
  transform-origin: center center 25px;
}

.rotating-text p .word .letter.out {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.7, 0.2);
}

.rotating-text p .word .letter.in {
  transition: 0.8s ease;
}

.rotating-text p .word .letter.behind {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.w-1 {
  color: #e74c3c;
}

.w-2 {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.w-3 {
  color: #3498db;
}

.w-4 {
  color: #28cc71;
}

.w-5 {
  color: #f1c40f;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotating-text">
  <p>Hello! My Name is </p>
  <p>
    <span class="word w-1" data-locale="en">Abhay_Chandra</span>
    <span class="word w-2" data-locale="hi-IN">अभय चंद्रा </span>
    <span class="word w-3" data-locale="ja-JP">アバイ・チャンドラ</span>
    <span class="word w-4" data-locale="ru-RU">Абхай Чандра</span>
    <span class="word w-5" data-locale="ko-KR">아바이 찬드라</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

If you need something with better browser support, I'd suggest splitting up your characters manually and storing them in an object:

```js
const localeGraphemes = {
  "en":["A","b","h","a","y","_","C","h","a","n","d","r","a"],
  "hi-IN":["अ","भ","य"," ","चं","द्रा"," "],
  "ja-JP":["ア","バ","イ","・","チ","ャ","ン","ド","ラ"],
  "ru-RU":["А","б","х","а","й"," ","Ч","а","н","д","р","а"],
  "ko-KR":["아","바","이"," ","찬","드","라"]
};
```

```js
"use strict";

const localeGraphemes = {
  "en":["A","b","h","a","y","_","C","h","a","n","d","r","a"],
  "hi-IN":["अ","भ","य"," ","चं","द्रा"," "],
  "ja-JP":["ア","バ","イ","・","チ","ャ","ン","ド","ラ"],
  "ru-RU":["А","б","х","а","й"," ","Ч","а","н","д","р","а"],
  "ko-KR":["아","바","이"," ","찬","드","라"]
};

let words = document.querySelectorAll(".word");
words.forEach((word) => {
  const locale = word.dataset.locale;
  let letters = localeGraphemes[locale];
  word.textContent = "";
  letters.forEach((letter) => {
    let span = document.createElement("span")
    span.textContent = letter;
    span.className = "letter";
    word.append(span);
  });
});

let currentWordIndex = 0;
let maxWordIndex = words.length - 1;
words[currentWordIndex].style.opacity = "1";

let rotateText = () => {
  let currentWord = words[currentWordIndex];
  let nextWord =
    currentWordIndex === maxWordIndex ? words[0] : words[currentWordIndex + 1];
  //rotate out letters of current word
  Array.from(currentWord.children).forEach((letter, i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      letter.className = "letter out";
    }, i * 80)
  });

  //reveal and rotate in letters of next word
  nextWord.style.opacity = "1";
  Array.from(nextWord.children).forEach((letter, i) => {
    letter.className = "letter behind";
    setTimeout(() => {
      letter.className = "letter in";
    }, 340 + i * 80)
  });
  currentWordIndex =
    currentWordIndex === maxWordIndex ? 0 : currentWordIndex + 1;
};

rotateText();
setInterval(rotateText, 4000);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #222;
}

.rotating-text {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateX(-80px);
}

.rotating-text p {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.rotating-text p .word {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
}

.rotating-text p .word .letter {
  transform-origin: center center 25px;
}

.rotating-text p .word .letter.out {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 0.7, 0.2);
}

.rotating-text p .word .letter.in {
  transition: 0.8s ease;
}

.rotating-text p .word .letter.behind {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.w-1 {
  color: #e74c3c;
}

.w-2 {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.w-3 {
  color: #3498db;
}

.w-4 {
  color: #28cc71;
}

.w-5 {
  color: #f1c40f;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotating-text">
  <p>Hello! My Name is </p>
  <p>
    <span class="word w-1" data-locale="en"></span>
    <span class="word w-2" data-locale="hi-IN"></span>
    <span class="word w-3" data-locale="ja-JP"></span>
    <span class="word w-4" data-locale="ru-RU"></span>
    <span class="word w-5" data-locale="ko-KR"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```